# Put multiple data-role into razor DropDownList

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is there a way to put multiple data-role into a razor code? I need it to tag my select list for a jquery tagger.

I need to make following:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Orientations", (SelectList)ViewBag.Orientations, "None", new { @multiple data-role="tagsinput", @class = "form-control" })
```

from:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Orientations", (SelectList)ViewBag.Orientations, "None", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

But it does not work by that way.
Thank you!

Comment: What's `multiple` with data-role?

Comment: It supposed to allow multi-values support in a select tag.

Comment: Have you tried `new { multiple, data-role="tagsinput",` or `new { multiple="multiple", data-role="tagsinput",`

Comment: Just use `@Html.ListBox()` or (better) `@Html.ListBoxFor()` which creates a multiple select (it add `multiple="multiple"` for you)

Comment: New { multiple="multiple" } - is working but when I want to put data-role..., I get Invalid anonymous type member declaration...
Thank you Stephen but I´d like to use the DropDownList, I´m used to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the hyphen in `data-role` to an underscrore (the html will be rendered with a hyphen).

```
@Html.DropDownList("Orientations", (SelectList)ViewBag.Orientations, "None", new { multiple="multiple", data_role="tagsinput", @class = "form-control" })
```

alternatively you can use

```
@Html.ListBox("Orientations", (SelectList)ViewBag.Orientations, "None", new { data_role="tagsinput", @class = "form-control" })
```

`@Html.ListBox` renders the attribute `multiple="multiple"` for you